# Azure pipelines wait until the previous build is finished

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline in ADO and I want that in the same time only one build is executed, so if I start the pipeline twice then only one is executed and the second one waits until the first is executed.
I tried using `batch` according to this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#batching-ci-runs
but it did not work, I started two runs and the second one did not wat for the first to finish.

Is there any built in way to achieve this or should I create my own script in a task which waits until the other runs are finished? I have a working solution for this using a bash script which checks if there is any previous run in progress and waits until it finished, but I feel that is a bit hacky, and I would prefer a build in solution if there is one.

Maybe this is somehow relevant code:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - release/*
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: Build
      project: <project-name>
      source: <source-pipeline-name>
      trigger: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting [`lockBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-190-update)

> You can configure the behavior of the exclusive lock check using the lockBehavior property, which has two values:
>
> - runLatest - Only the latest run acquires the lock to the resource. This is the default value if no lockBehavior is specified.
> - sequential - All runs acquire the lock sequentially to the protected resource.

```
lockBehavior: sequential
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    steps:
    - script: Hey!
```

But for this you need to use exclusive lock on environment (so you need to use deplpyment jobs)

[image]

or in variable group used in the pipeline:

[image]

Here you have documentation about [exclusiveLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/stages-stage?view=azure-pipelines#exclusive-lock)